# Dynamically Defining a jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I am trying to make an ad-hoc query page for our ASP.NET MVC 2 application.  This page is secured and used strictly for technical administrative access on our intranet.  We want the ability to query a handful of tables and I don't want to have to have a page/grid per query.  I have an MVC controller that returns a JSON result that includes the following values (I got these from client-side javascript alerts, so I know this is what these values look like "at the grid"):

colNames contains:

```
['AccountID','ClientID']
```

colModel contains:

```
[{editable:false,index:'AccountID',jsonmap:'AccountID',key:false,name:'AccountID',resizable:true,search:false,sortable:true,width:300},
 {editable:false,index:'ClientID',jsonmap:'ClientID',key:false,name:'ClientID',resizable:true,search:false,sortable:true,width:300}]
```

colData contains:

```
{total:1,page:1,records:1,rows:[{AccountID:1,ClientID:1}]}
```

And, on the client, my jqGrid looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%: Url.Action("GetData", "Support") %>',
        data: { query: 'foo' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {

            alert(result.colNames);
            alert(result.colModel);
            alert(result.colData);

            jQuery('#QueryGrid').jqGrid({
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                shrinkToFit: true,
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                colNames: result.colNames,
                colModel: result.colModel,
                datastr: result.colData,
                viewrecords: true
            });
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert(x.readyState + ' ' + x.status + ' ' + e.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

I have been putting this together based on a couple of related posts/replies here at Stack Overflow, as well as the jqGrid wiki.  I am pretty sure that I am very, very close ... but it's just not working out.

The problem I am having is that the jqGrid throws an error "Length of colNames <> colModel!" and I can't seem to figure out what it is about my JSON strings that it doesn't like.

Anyone see what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the data which you receive as `result.colNames` and `result.colModel` **are strings and not objects**.

```
var cn = ['AccountID','ClientID'];
var cm = [
    {editable:false,index:'AccountID',jsonmap:'AccountID',key:false,name:'AccountID',
     resizable:true,search:false,sortable:true,width:300},
    {editable:false,index:'ClientID',jsonmap:'ClientID',key:false,name:'ClientID',
     resizable:true,search:false,sortable:true,width:300}];
var cd = '{total:1,page:1,records:1,rows:[{AccountID:1,ClientID:3}]}';
jQuery('#QueryGrid').jqGrid({
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: cn,
    colModel: cm,
    datastr: cd,
    viewrecords: true
});
```

By the way some properties which you use in the `colModel` parameters are default. The parameter `shrinkToFit: true` is also default. So you can reduce to

```
[{index:'AccountID',jsonmap:'AccountID',name:'AccountID',search:false,width:300},
 {index:'ClientID',jsonmap:'ClientID',name:'ClientID',search:false,width:300}]
```

If you will use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, cell:"" }` then it can be more shorter

```
[{index:'AccountID',name:'AccountID',search:false,width:300},
 {index:'ClientID',name:'ClientID',search:false,width:300}]
```

Probably what you really wanted is to send the `result.colNames` and `result.colModel` as a JSON strings which can be converted to objects for example withj respect of [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). In the case you should change a little the format of the data in the `result.colNames` and `result.colModel`. Following code will also work

```
var cnStr = '["AccountID","ClientID"]';
var cmStr = '[{"index":"AccountID","name":"AccountID","search":false,"width":300},{"index":"ClientID","name":"ClientID","search":false,"width":300}]';
var cd = '{total:1,page:1,records:1,rows:[{AccountID:1,ClientID:3}]}';
jQuery('#QueryGrid').jqGrid({
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, cell:"" },
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        height:'auto',
        colNames: jQuery.parseJSON(cnStr),
        colModel: jQuery.parseJSON(cmStr),
        datastr: cd,
        viewrecords: true
    });
```

One more small remark. You don't use `key:true` or `id` values in the jqGrid data. It is potentially dangerous. You should understend that jqGrid use id="1", id="2" and so on if no `id` exist in the data. The problem can be if you use two or more such grids on one page. You can receive **double ids** very easy which is not allowed.